# PayPal REST with Node.js not responding in sandbox mode

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been learning how integrate paypal restful api to my website using Node.js.
I am using paypal-rest-sdk module for node.js

Everything was working fine. I could make credit card test payments and paypal test payments.

Today out of no where I could not get a response from paypal. This is the error I am getting:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 173.0.82.78:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:849:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:872:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
```

I have tried both live and sandbox with similar results.

I am using code right off the github page: 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_credit_card.js

Everything has been working the last 2 days. I have been studying and learning the responses paypal give for certain requests.

What could have caused this? Is it me or Paypal? Is it because I am using localhost? If it is PayPal. How often does this happen? I got the same results using live mode so Im kind of curious to how often I will encounter things like this using paypal as my merchant

Comment: So it looks like you can reach out our IP but just are experiencing some network issues that are creating delays. Did you already tried to traceroute the host? Could you please provide the result of a traceroute or a cURL command? Also, are you using a test credit card? Test cards number like “411111111111111” could cause timeouts. Thank you in advance for the information provided.